# How do destructors work in a simple program?

Tags: c++, constructor, destructor

I don't understand the output of this program :

```
class A {
public :
    A()  { cout << "A()"  << endl; }
    ~A() { cout << "~A()" << endl; }
};

A f (A & a) { 
    return a;
}

int main() {
    A a ;
    a = f(a);

    return 0;
}
```

I expected

```
A()
~A()
```

because I only created one `A` object : `a`. However, the output is

```
A()
~A()
~A()
```

Do you know why that is ?

---

**FOLLOWUP QUESTION**

Okay, so whenever calling `f`, I construct a copy of an `A`, so I have 1 call to the copy constructor and one call to the destructor...

Say now my main function is :

```
int main() {
    A a ;
    A b = f(a);
    cout << "returning 0" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I would expect the output to be

```
A(),
A(const A &) (for using f(a))
~A()         (for deleting temporary f(a))
returning 0
~A()         (destroying B)
~A()         (destroying A)
```

But the output is

```
A() 
A(const& A) 
returning 0
~A()
~A()
```

Why is that ?

Comment: Try adding this line: `A(const A&) { cout << "A(const A&)" << endl; }`.

Comment: You are missing copy construction and copy assignment (and, to be complete; the move operations as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only created one object explicitly, but you are creating one object here:

```
A f (A & a) { return a ;} //when returning A
```

as you are copying the object to pass it back from f, that copy is being constructed by the default copy constructor as you didn't provide one.
If you change your class to this:

```
class A {
public :
    A () { cout << "A() " << endl;}
    A (const A &) { cout << "A(const &) " << endl;}
    ~A () { cout << "~A ()" << endl; }
};
```

you will see the copy constructor being called (as you are providing one).

Comment: Yes of course, my bad, I fixed the answer. Thanks @Evg

Comment: Pablo Yaggi, @Evg what about the followup ? I'm having trouble putting it all together.

Answer (score 0):

*An answer to the follow-up question.*

Destructors pair with constructors. Why do you expect two constructions and three destructions? That's not possible in a correct program.

```
A b = f(a);
```

is not an assignment (in contrast to `a = f(a)`), but a construction ([copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization)). You don't see a construction and destruction of a temporary object here thanks to the [return value optimization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) (RVO): a compiler is allowed to elide an unnecessary copy and construct `b` as if by `A b(a);`.

Before C++17 this mechanism is optional. You can [compile](https://godbolt.org/z/97dG69) this code with GCC with `-std=c++11 -fno-elide-constructors` options to spot a temporary:

```
A()              construct (a)
A(const A&)      construct a temporary copy of (a)
A(const A&)      construct (b) from that temporary
~A()             destruct that temporary
returning 0 
~A()             destruct (b)
~A()             destruct (a)
```

Since C++17 this type of copy elision is mandatory, so you'll always see only two constructions and destructions:

```
A()              construct (a)
A(const A&)      construct (b) from (a)
returning 0 
~A()             destruct (b)
~A()             destruct (a)
```